# How to apply custom function to a pyspark dataframe column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```py
@pandas_udf(StringType())
def convert_num(y):
    try:
        if y.endswith('K')==True:
            y = list(y)
            y.remove(y[''.join(y).find('K')])
            if ''.join(y).startswith('€')==True:
                y.remove(y[''.join(y).find('€')])
            else:
                pass
            try :
                return str(int(''.join(y))*1000)
            except:
                return y
        elif y.endswith('M')==True:
            y = list(y)
            y.remove(y[''.join(y).find('M')])
            if ''.join(y).startswith('€')==True:
                y = list(y)
                y.remove(y[''.join(y).find('€')])
            else:
                pass
            try :
                return str(float(''.join(y))*1000000)
            except:
                return y
    except:
        return y
```

I have the above UDF as a pandas UDF.

There is a column in my spark dataframe named `Value`. I want to apply that function and transform it.

I used this

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.select(convert_num(df.Value).alias('converted')).take(5)
```

But it is returning me the same values instead of transforming it.You can see the result below.

```
Row(Player_name='T. Almada', Images='https://cdn.sofifa.net/players/245/371/24_60.png', Age=22, National_team='Argentina', Positions="['CAM', 'CM', 'CF']", Overall=79, Potential_overall=87, Current_club='Atlanta United', Current_contract='2022 ~ 2025', **Value='€39.5M'**, Wage='€10K', Total_stats=2050, **converted_amount='€39.5M'**)
```

Where i am doing wrong.

Comment: check if there are any exception.

Comment: According to doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html `y` will be iterator

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `@pandas_udf` decorator means that `convert_num(y)` expects that `y` is a `Series`, but you're treating y like a string.

Also from a debugging standpoint, having multiple try/except blocks where you return `y` in the `except` block will make it difficult to determine the source of any incorrect code in one or more of the try blocks (if you get the same column values back, then there was an exception thrown somewhere, but from which except block?).

Notice that if you remove the outer try/except block, then running `df.select(convert_num(df.Value)).take(5)` will throw:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

You can fix this by restructuring your convert_num function to treat input y as a Series, and output a Series while still using the same string logic:

```
@pandas_udf(StringType())
def convert_num(s):
    def convert_string(y):
        if y.endswith('K')==True:
            y = list(y)
            y.remove(y[''.join(y).find('K')])
            if ''.join(y).startswith('€')==True:
                y.remove(y[''.join(y).find('€')])
            else:
                pass
            try:
                return str(int(''.join(y))*1000)
            except:
                return y
        elif y.endswith('M')==True:
            y = list(y)
            y.remove(y[''.join(y).find('M')])
            if ''.join(y).startswith('€')==True:
                y = list(y)
                y.remove(y[''.join(y).find('€')])
            else:
                pass
            try:
                return str(float(''.join(y))*1000000)
            except:
                return y
        else:
            return y
    return s.apply(convert_string)
```

Sample PySpark DataFrame `df`:

```
+-----------+------+
|Player_name| Value|
+-----------+------+
|    PlayerA|€39.5M|
|    PlayerB| €390K|
+-----------+------+
```

Output `df` after converting `Value` column:

```
df.select(convert_num(df.Value).alias('converted'))

+----------+
| converted|
+----------+
|39500000.0|
|    390000|
+----------+
```

Comment: Hi how can i apply the function without using pandas_udf, and using transform() function

Comment: @smrutiranjansamal the `transform` function is for columns containing an array. i don't understand how that applies to the question you asked since the `Value` column contains strings. also if you don't want to use `pandas_udf`, then why did you ask specifically about pandas_udf? if you want to use transform, i think you should write a separate question

Answer (score 0):

As someone asked in the comments, how to achieve a custom transformation in `spark` without using `pandas`, here is a simple example:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
>>> df = session.createDataFrame((("Jhon Doe", 1995), ("Elvis Kribs", 1998)))
>>> df = df.toDF("Name", "YOB")
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- YOB: long (nullable = true)

>>> @udf
... def custom_tranformaion(val): return val + " UDF Value!"
...
>>> df.withColumn("TransformedValue", custom_tranformaion("Name")).show(truncate=False)
+-----------+----+----------------------+
|Name       |YOB |TransformedValue      |
+-----------+----+----------------------+
|Jhon Doe   |1995|Jhon Doe UDF Value!   |
|Elvis Kribs|1998|Elvis Kribs UDF Value!|
+-----------+----+----------------------+
```

Notice the `@udf` decorator, which take a value and returns transformed value that will become part of dataframe.

Note: It's usually hard for spark optimizer to optimize code inside a udf.

References:
[1](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/#google_vignette)
[2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html)